# Get rectangular shape from very noisy image Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Need to get rectangular shapes from a noisy color segmented image.
The problem is that sometimes the object isn't uniformly the correct color causing holes in the image, or sometimes reflection of the object in the background cause noise/false positive for the color segmentation.

The object could be in any position of the image and of any unknown rectangular size, the holes can occur anywhere inside the object and the noise could occur on any side of the object.
The only known constant is that the object is rectangular in shape.

Whats the best way to filter out that noise to the left of the object and get a bounding box around the object?

Using erosion would remove the detail from the bottom of the object and would cause the size of the bounding box to be wrong

[image]

Comment: There's probably better preprocessing you can do. Can you post an example input image?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I am using histogram backprojection so I don't think there's much more I can do for preprocessing?

Comment: Would it be correct to say this image is generated via inverse Radon transform then? How many angles?

Comment: Maybe for a first pass I'd try to do connected component analysis to find the biggest blob, and then restrict around that area which should remove most of the noise to the left. Then you can look into morphology (opening in particular) for that ROI to combine it all into one blob which you can then try to get some external contours of.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because of my rep, but I think you could try to analyse the colored image using other color spaces. Create a upper and a lower bound of the color you want until it selects the object, leaving you with less noise, which you can filter with erode/dilate/opening/closing.

For example, in my project I wanted to found a bounding box of a color-changing green rectangle, so I went and tried a lot of diferent color spaces with a lot of diferent upper/lower bounds until I finally got something worthy. Here is a nice read of what I'm talking about : [Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)

You can also try filtering the object by área, after dilating it (you dilate first so the closer points connect to one another, while the more distant ones, which are the noise, don't, creating a big rectangle with lots of noise, but then you filter by a big área).

Comment: The problem is that I am using histogram backprojection to get this image so I cant use another color space to get less noise.
And dilating too much to close the holes will cause the object to merge with the noise on the right

Comment: @Ta946 is the noise always at the side of the rectangle and has the same size? Maybe you can find a bounding box for the rectangle + noise and then divide its width by 2 or something

Answer (score 0):

One method is to take histogram projection on both the horizontal and vertical axes, and select the intersection of ranges that have high projections.

The projections are just totals of object pixels in each row and each column. When you are looking for only one rectangle, the values indicated the probablity of the row/column belonging to the rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood 100%. Do you mean to create a grid of rows and counting the number of the pixels in each row?

Comment: Correct. To repeat, create an integer array that has as many elements as the number of rows in the image, and then record the count of object pixels in each row. Then you can do the same thing for columns. If you have only one rectangle and it is not rotated much, you should be able to identify its location by looking at these two arrays.